# How could i get the kafka server's offset in this time?

Tags: offset

I have keep my kafka client offset yet, but the kafka server were delete data in a time delta.

so i can't get anything when i call the kafka server for data .

How could i get the kafka server's offset in this time?

I just want to get data from now on

我有保存我的卡夫卡客户端偏移还，但卡夫卡服务器会在一段时间后删除数据。

因此，当我向卡夫卡服务器要数据时，我不能得到任何东西。

我怎么能得到卡夫卡服务器现在的偏移量？

我只是想从现在开始获取数据

Answer (score 0):

SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(topic, partition, time, 1)

time should be kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime() , get minimal valid offset